# Laravel MTG DB Design

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design

I'm pretty new to laravel and DB design in general, and I'm creating a card database for Magic the Gathering. I'm having trouble figuring out how to create the tables as they relate to legality in a given format. There are about 15 formats and each format can have 1 of 4 values.

For example:

```
${card name} is [legal, not legal, banned, restricted] in ${format}
```

At some point I'll probably want to be able to query all cards in a given format that have some value and so on...

I'm guessing `formats`, `card_singles` and `legalities` will all need a table, but I can't work out how to relate them so they make sense.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for the Database Admin Stack Exchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'll post there as well

Comment: No problem! You might get an answer here, but typically not for DB design questions. As a thought, I think you have the right idea; something that allows you to specify legality for a specif card and format, like `card_legalities`, `card_id`, `format_id`, `legality` (or `legiality_id`), etc etc.